# Cannot instantiate the type rankup

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Cannot instantiate the type rankup - line 61
I don't quite understand why this is happening:

```
package net.minebloxmc.main;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import commands.rankup;



public class Main extends JavaPlugin {



    public FileConfiguration config = getConfig();
    public void onEnable() {
        registerCommands();



        config.options().copyDefaults(true);
        saveConfig();

    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
        if (commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("ranks")) {
            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                player.sendMessage("[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Ranks" + ChatColor.WHITE + "]");

                if (args.length == 0) {
                    String[] classes = getConfig().getString("Ranks.Names").split(",");
                    String[] prices = getConfig().getString("Ranks.Prices").split(",");

                    for(int i = 0; i< classes.length;i++){
                        sender.sendMessage("[" + ChatColor.GOLD + classes[i] + ChatColor.WHITE + "] " + ChatColor.BLUE + "This gives you the " + classes[i] + " rank!" + " Price: $" + prices[i] );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    public void onDisable() {
        PluginDescriptionFile pdfFile = getDescription();
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");

        logger.info(pdfFile.getName() + " is now disabled (V." + pdfFile.getVersion() + ")");


    }
    public void registerCommands() {
        getCommand("rankup").setExecutor(new rankup(this));

    }
}
```

Here's rankup.java:

```
package commands;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.OfflinePlayer;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.permissions.PermissionAttachment;
import org.bukkit.permissions.PermissionAttachmentInfo;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;

import com.earth2me.essentials.api.Economy;
import com.earth2me.essentials.api.UserDoesNotExistException;

import net.minebloxmc.main.Main;


public abstract class rankup implements CommandExecutor {

    public Main pluginn;

    public rankup(Main plugin) {
        this.pluginn = plugin;
    }

    protected static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");
    protected Plugin plugin = null;


    abstract public String getName();


    abstract public boolean isEnabled();


    abstract public boolean hasSuperPermsCompat();


    @Deprecated
    public boolean has(String world, String player, String permission) {
        if (world == null) {
            return playerHas((String) null, player, permission);
        }
        return playerHas(world, player, permission);
    }


    @Deprecated
    public boolean has(World world, String player, String permission) {
        if (world == null) {
            return playerHas((String) null, player, permission);
        }
        return playerHas(world.getName(), player, permission);
    }


    public boolean has(CommandSender sender, String permission) {
        return sender.hasPermission(permission);
    }


    public boolean has(Player player, String permission) {
        return player.hasPermission(permission);
    }


    @Deprecated
    abstract public boolean playerHas(String world, String player, String permission);


    @Deprecated
    public boolean playerHas(World world, String player, String permission) {
        if (world == null) {
            return playerHas((String) null, player, permission);
        }
        return playerHas(world.getName(), player, permission);
    }


    public boolean playerHas(String world, OfflinePlayer player, String permission) {
        if (world == null) {
            return has((String) null, player.getName(), permission);
        }
        return has(world, player.getName(), permission);
    }


    public boolean playerHas(Player player, String permission) {
        return has(player, permission);
    }


    @Deprecated
    abstract public boolean playerAdd(String world, String player, String permission);


    @Deprecated
    public boolean playerAdd(World world, String player, String permission) {
        if (world == null) {
            return playerAdd((String) null, player, permission);
        }
        return playerAdd(world.getName(), player, permission);
    }


    public boolean playerAdd(String world, OfflinePlayer player, String permission) {
        if (world == null) {
            return playerAdd((String) null, player.getName(), permission);
        }
        return playerAdd(world, player.getName(), permission);
    }


    public boolean playerAdd(Player player, String permission) {
        return playerAdd(player.getWorld().getName(), player, permission);
    }


    @Deprecated
    public boolean playerAddTransient(String player, String permission) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        Player p = plugin.getServer().getPlayer(player);
        if (p == null) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(getName() + " does not support offline player transient permissions!");
        }
        return playerAddTransient(p, permission);
    }


    public boolean playerAddTransient(OfflinePlayer player, String permission) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        if (player.isOnline()) {
            return playerAddTransient((Player) player, permission);
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(getName() + " does not support offline player transient permissions!");
    }


    public boolean playerAddTransient(Player player, String permission) {
        for (PermissionAttachmentInfo paInfo : player.getEffectivePermissions()) {
            if (paInfo.getAttachment() != null && paInfo.getAttachment().getPlugin().equals(plugin)) {
                paInfo.getAttachment().setPermission(permission, true);
                return true;
            }
        }

        PermissionAttachment attach = player.addAttachment(plugin);
        attach.setPermission(permission, true);

        return true;
    }


    public boolean playerAddTransient(String worldName, OfflinePlayer player, String permission) {
        return playerAddTransient(worldName, player.getName(), permission);
    }


    public boolean playerAddTransient(String worldName, Player player, String permission) {
        return playerAddTransient(player, permission);
    }


    @Deprecated
    public boolean playerAddTransient(String worldName, String player, String permission) {
        Player p = plugin.getServer().getPlayer(player);
        if (p == null) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(getName() + " does not support offline player transient permissions!");
        }
        return playerAddTransient(p, permission);
    }


    @Deprecated
    public boolean playerRemoveTransient(String worldName, String player,     String permission) {
        Player p = plugin.getServer().getPlayer(player);
        if (p == null)
            return false;

        return playerRemoveTransient(p, permission);
    }


    public boolean playerRemoveTransient(String worldName, OfflinePlayer player, String permission) {
        return playerRemoveTransient(worldName, player.getName(), permission);
    }


    public boolean playerRemoveTransient(String worldName, Player player, String permission) {
        return playerRemoveTransient(worldName, (OfflinePlayer) player, permission);
    }


    @Deprecated
    abstract public boolean playerRemove(String world, String player, String permission);


    public boolean playerRemove(String world, OfflinePlayer player, String permission) {
        if (world == null) {
            return playerRemove((String) null, player.getName(), permission);
        }
        return playerRemove(world, player.getName(), permission);
    }


    @Deprecated
    public boolean playerRemove(World world, String player, String permission) {
        if (world == null) {
            return playerRemove((String) null, player, permission);
        }
        return playerRemove(world.getName(), player, permission);
    }

    public boolean playerRemove(Player player, String permission) {
        return playerRemove(player.getWorld().getName(), player, permission);
    }


    @Deprecated
    public boolean playerRemoveTransient(String player, String permission) {
        Player p = plugin.getServer().getPlayer(player);
        if (p == null)
            return false;

        return playerRemoveTransient(p, permission);
    }


    public boolean playerRemoveTransient(OfflinePlayer player, String permission) {
        if (player.isOnline()) {
            return playerRemoveTransient((Player) player, permission);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public boolean playerRemoveTransient(Player player, String permission) {
        for (PermissionAttachmentInfo paInfo : player.getEffectivePermissions()) {
            if (paInfo.getAttachment() != null && paInfo.getAttachment().getPlugin().equals(plugin)) {
                paInfo.getAttachment().unsetPermission(permission);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    abstract public boolean groupHas(String world, String group, String permission);


    public boolean groupHas(World world, String group, String permission) {
        if (world == null) {
            return groupHas((String) null, group, permission);
        }
        return groupHas(world.getName(), group, permission);
    }


    abstract public boolean groupAdd(String world, String group, String permission);


    public boolean groupAdd(World world, String group, String permission) {
        if (world == null) {
            return groupAdd((String) null, group, permission);
        }
        return groupAdd(world.getName(), group, permission);
    }


    abstract public boolean groupRemove(String world, String group, String permission);


    public boolean groupRemove(World world, String group, String permission) {
        if (world == null) {
            return groupRemove((String) null, group, permission);
        }
        return groupRemove(world.getName(), group, permission);
    }


    @Deprecated
    abstract public boolean playerInGroup(String world, String player, String group);


    @Deprecated
    public boolean playerInGroup(World world, String player, String group) {
        if (world == null) {
            return playerInGroup((String) null, player, group);
        }
        return playerInGroup(world.getName(), player, group);
    }


    public boolean playerInGroup(String world, OfflinePlayer player, String group) {
        if (world == null) {
            return playerInGroup((String) null, player.getName(), group);
        }
        return playerInGroup(world, player.getName(), group);
    }


    public boolean playerInGroup(Player player, String group) {
        return playerInGroup(player.getWorld().getName(), player, group);
    }


    @Deprecated
    abstract public boolean playerAddGroup(String world, String player, String group);


    @Deprecated
    public boolean playerAddGroup(World world, String player, String group) {
        if (world == null) {
            return playerAddGroup((String) null, player, group);
        }
        return playerAddGroup(world.getName(), player, group);
    }


    public boolean playerAddGroup(String world, OfflinePlayer player, String group) {
        if (world == null) {
            return playerAddGroup((String) null, player.getName(), group);
        }
        return playerAddGroup(world, player.getName(), group);
    }


    public boolean playerAddGroup(Player player, String group) {
        return playerAddGroup(player.getWorld().getName(), player, group);
    }


    @Deprecated
    abstract public boolean playerRemoveGroup(String world, String player, String group);


    @Deprecated
    public boolean playerRemoveGroup(World world, String player, String group) {
        if (world == null) {
            return playerRemoveGroup((String) null, player, group);
        }
        return playerRemoveGroup(world.getName(), player, group);
    }


    public boolean playerRemoveGroup(String world, OfflinePlayer player, String group) {
        if (world == null) {
            return playerRemoveGroup((String) null, player.getName(), group);
        }
        return playerRemoveGroup(world, player.getName(), group);
    }


    public boolean playerRemoveGroup(Player player, String group) {
        return playerRemoveGroup(player.getWorld().getName(), player, group);
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated As of VaultAPI 1.4 use {@link #getPlayerGroups(String, OfflinePlayer)} instead.
     */
    @Deprecated
    abstract public String[] getPlayerGroups(String world, String player);


    @Deprecated
    public String[] getPlayerGroups(World world, String player) {
        if (world == null) {
            return getPlayerGroups((String) null, player);
        }
        return getPlayerGroups(world.getName(), player);
    }


    public String[] getPlayerGroups(String world, OfflinePlayer player) {
        return getPlayerGroups(world, player.getName());
    }


    public String[] getPlayerGroups(Player player) {
        return getPlayerGroups(player.getWorld().getName(), player);
    }


    @Deprecated
    abstract public String getPrimaryGroup(String world, String player);


    @Deprecated
    public String getPrimaryGroup(World world, String player) {
        if (world == null) {
            return getPrimaryGroup((String) null, player);
        }
        return getPrimaryGroup(world.getName(), player);
    }


    public String getPrimaryGroup(String world, OfflinePlayer player) {
        return getPrimaryGroup(world, player.getName());
    }


    public String getPrimaryGroup(Player player) {
        return getPrimaryGroup(player.getWorld().getName(), player);
    }


    abstract public String[] getGroups();


    abstract public boolean hasGroupSupport();

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("You must be a player");
            return false;
        }

        Player player = (Player) sender;
        String playere = player.getName();
        String world = plugin.getConfig().getString("World.World");
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String A = "A";
    if (player.getLocation().getWorld().getName().equals(world)) {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "Correct world: " + world + "!");
        try {
            if (Economy.hasEnough(playere, 100)) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "You have enough!");

                getPrimaryGroup(world, playere);

            }
        } catch (UserDoesNotExistException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Incorrect world! You need to be in world: " + world + "!");
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

This is for a bukkit plugin I am working on, and I am trying to make it find the group of the user running the command /rankup.

Comment: rankup is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Why are you declaring `rankup` abstract? Abstract classes are meant to be extended by other classes. Also, class names should start with a capital letter as per convention and readability.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your "rankup" class as abstract. This means you can't instantiate it via "new" like you're trying to do in your registerCommand method. You need to create a concrete subclass of rankup that implements your abstract methods and instantiate that instead.

Comment: How would I do that (I know that is a REALLY stupid question, but as they say... Code to learn)